# Two-Dimension array value replace with array

Tags: c#, arrays, replace

I'm using C#. I want to replace value in Two-Dimension array with another Two-Dimension array.

Array what want to replace value is

```
{
    {100, 100, 100, 100},
    {100, 100, 100, 100},
    {100, 100, 100, 100},
    {100, 100, 100, 100}
}
```

and, Some array what to replace value to that array is

```
{
    {500,500},
    {500,500}
}
```

and I expected :

```
{
    {100,100,100,100},
    {100,500,500,100},
    {100,500,500,100},
    {100,100,100,100}
}
```

Comment: You'll need to post your code if you want any hope of assistance.

Comment: and what is the logic behind this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple to understand code with two loops:

```
var bigger = new int[,]
{
    {100, 101, 102, 103, 104},
    {100, 100, 100, 100, 100},
    {100, 100, 100, 100, 100},
    {100, 100, 100, 100, 100},
};

var smaller = new int[,]
{
    {1, 2},
    {3, 4},
};

ReplaceValues (bigger, smaller, 3, 2);
```

and static method:

```
public static void ReplaceValues (int[,] destinationArray, int[,] replaceWith, int columnOffset, int rowOffset)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < replaceWith.GetLength (0); row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column < replaceWith.GetLength (1); column++)
        {
            destinationArray[row + rowOffset, column + columnOffset] = replaceWith[row, column];
        }
    }
}
```

Of course you should upgrade this code depending on your requirements.

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to compare the dimension of these array : 
The big array is : 4x4 and the small is 2x2(double). So loop through the big array is :

```
bigarray[i x 2 + 1, j x 2 + 1] = smallarray [i,j].
```

So the formular can be:

```
bigarray[i x compare_value + 1, j x compare_value + 1] = smallarray [i,j]
```

With `compare_value = bigarray/ smallaray`.